# MS Access find unmatched finds items that should have matched

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access database with a table of data from the university accounting system and another table with data from our local invoice system. I want to find the invoices in the local table that are not in the university accounting system table. The invoice number (as text, because our invoice numbers may have text) is my match point between the two tables.

The problem is that some of the unmatched invoice numbers SHOULD have found a match. The numbers appear to be exactly the same in both tables. When I query either table for a specific unmatched invoice number, I find it. The formatting of both table’s invoice number field is the same. An example is invoice number 100512. The same number is in both tables but my query says no match found.

Comment: We would need to see some data and your query. Also does the data look the same when you export it to a text format like CSV?

Comment: Okay. I finally have gotten back to this. The problem is really bad. Nearly 5000 records don't find a match. I've verified that three of them should have found a match. I can verify several more, if preferred. No carriage return option in this, huh? Not much space either. The query: SELECT DISTINCT [Sum-Mpost].InvNum, [Sum-Mpost].PostDate, [BAIRS-SUM-ALL].[Voucher Invoice Id], [BAIRS-SUM-ALL].[Accounting Period], [Sum-Mpost].TotalC
FROM [Sum-Mpost] LEFT JOIN [BAIRS-SUM-ALL] ON [Sum-Mpost].InvNum = [BAIRS-SUM-ALL].[Voucher Invoice Id]
WHERE ((([BAIRS-SUM-ALL].[Voucher Invoice Id]) Is Null));

Comment: In words, the query matches on invoice number between query1 and query2. It identifies all invoice numbers in query 1 (Sum-Mpost) that are not found in query 2 (BAIRS-SUM-ALL). The original tables are BAIRS and mpost. In those tables the invoice  number field is text, because there are text characters in the invoice numbers. Not everything in query1 will match an invoice in query2. The data in query2 is a week or so behind, but I shouldn't be missing thousands of invoices.

Comment: I don't know how to export the query results to csv. Both original tables were imported from Excel. Care was taken that the invoice number was always imported as text. 
Unmathced query results snippet:
InvNum PostDate Voucher Invoice Id Accounting Period TotalC
100007847 8/12/2015   865.6
100008402 8/26/2015   70.63
100043 11/24/2015   5544

Results of querying the original table (BAIRS) for the three invoice numbers above:
Voucher Invoice Id Actuals Amount
100008402 70.63
100007847 865.6
100043 5,544.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Matching on invoice number between the original tables and querying for the invoice numbers that didn't match, listed above, I find matches. So the problem is in what the sub-query is doing to the type of the data when I run the query. I see one of the sub-queies was omitting some data. I fixed that, but not everything finds a match that should. @Pekka웃